# Sharepoint Subsite Creation Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, sub-site

I am trying to create a new subsite and it keeps showing up as the image below.[image]

I have tried making it with different templates and have had other people make a new one, and they are having the same issue.
All the web parts I add have this section of symbols which covers up everything and doesn't display the web part like it should. I also do not have the gear in the top right corner as I do on all the other sharepoint pages. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Add site into trusted site and compare the results.

You need to verify that the "create sites" is checked within the Full Control permission level.

Navigate to the site collection->Site settings->Site permissions->Permission Levels->verify that the "create sites" is checked within the permission level.